# how can I generate a random ipv4 address using shuf command?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

how can I generate a random ipv4 address using shuf command? I don t want a function for a script or anything like that just a command like shuf or other command if this one doesn t work.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can run the following:

```
for i in {1..4} ; do
    printf '%d\n' {1..255} | shuf | head -n1
done | tr '\n' . | sed 's/\.$//'
```

It shuffles the numbers 1..255, head selects the first one, the loop does that four times, then newlines are replaced by a dot and the final dot is removed by sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v min=1 -v max=255 'BEGIN{srand(); for(i=1;i<=4;i++){ printf int(min+rand()*(max-min+1)); if(i<4){printf "."}}}'
```

If you are ok with using `awk`, there is an inbuilt capability in `awk` to generate random number.